error en la descarga de datos desde firebase a mi pagina react, no encuentro su solucion
necesito colaboracion para solucionar los siguientes errores que arroja la consola de mi pagina cuando solicito la descarga de datos de firebase, he cambiado el codigo de descarga de datos variadas ocasiones, solo he conseguido que funcione correctamente pero los errores permanecen en la consola, los errores son los siguientes: ---------------------------Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.
firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=8AgI3xPqAst9aHPEmr_cF037LrMpLyf70_Ju-CRVtgo&VER=8&database=projects%2Fgestion-tienda-dcd4c%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=n47PpMBZxpYbhXuxYJ-VeA&AID=0&CI=1&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=vod2c3ukbswm&t=1:1
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

logger.ts:115 [2024-05-17T20:12:32.821Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.11.1): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x4ade0b5f transport errored: Qd
defaultLogHandler @ logger.ts:115
firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=6ri4Cs3SUEpi-BjzktZRuyYx9ndV-5qtLo2fwnydlqI&VER=8&database=projects%2Fgestion-tienda-dcd4c%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=LUIeV8SbbI7BU5ukzjydow&AID=0&CI=1&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=czz1vtkgypo3&t=1:1
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

logger.ts:115 [2024-05-17T20:12:34.743Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.11.1): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x4ade0b60 transport errored: Qd
defaultLogHandler @ logger.ts:115
firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=DN-qgT4IvL3HJBhI8fABhbWj4YUNB_NwYZU2rNRnk7U&VER=8&database=projects%2Fgestion-tienda-dcd4c%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=OxWskhe7UnqtHLA9CHsFBQ&AID=0&CI=1&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=feanaw8kadpr&t=1:1
   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

logger.ts:115 [2024-05-17T20:12:36.581Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.11.1): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream 0x4ade0b61 transport errored: Qd
mi codigo de descarga de datos es el siguiente el cual es pasado como prop para ser reutilizado eficientemente en cada una de las paginas a las cuales se aplicará la descarga...
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
    import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
    import { db } from '../../firebase';
    
const FirebaseDataFetcher = ({ collectionName }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, collectionName));
        const newData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
        setData(newData);
    }, [collectionName]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);

    return data;
};

export default FirebaseDataFetcher;

luego este codigo es aplicado de la siguiente manera en el cartContext que engloba todas las lineas de codigo, ya que esa descarga deseo utilizarla en gran parte de la web
const categoriesData = FirebaseDataFetcher({ collectionName:'categorias' });
  const subCategoriesData = FirebaseDataFetcher({ collectionName:'categoMarca' });
  const productsData = FirebaseDataFetcher({ collectionName:'productos' });

  useEffect(() => {
    setCartCategoryData(categoriesData);
  }, [categoriesData]); 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setCartSubCategoryData(subCategoriesData);
  }, [subCategoriesData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCartProductData(productsData);
  }, [productsData]);

de esta forma, cargo los datos en el cartContext para exportarlos como props y pasar a ser reutilizados en otra pagina de la siguiente manera...
const { cartProductData, cartCategoryData } = useCart();

    useEffect(() => {
        setData(cartProductData);
    }, [cartProductData])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setCategoria(cartCategoryData);
    }, [cartCategoryData])

con esos useEffect, logro cargar todo en sus respectivas variables para luego ser importadas en el codigo, recorriendo esas variables y desarmandolas tanto en productos como categorias,subcategorias,etc, individualmente.
Si alguien sabe la respuesta o conoce la solución, le agradeceria un monton ya que me ayuda increiblemente. Muchisimas gracias

pero estas usando https o http???

El código de error 404 hace pensar que estás intentando acceder a recursos que no existen en Firebase. ¿Revisaste que las rutas que se están produciendo en collectionName
son correctas?

si estan correctas, debido a que descarga los datos pero luego de varias recargas de la misma pagina, empieza a devolver el error

Lidiar con errores en la descarga de datos desde Firebase en una aplicación React puede ser frustrante. Aquí te dejo algunos pasos y consejos que podrían ayudarte a solucionar el problema:
Verifica la Configuración de Firebase: Asegúrate de que todas las claves API y la configuración de Firebase en tu aplicación React estén correctamente establecidas. Un error común es tener configuraciones incorrectas o incompletas que impiden una correcta comunicación con Firebase.
Revisar los Permisos de Firebase: Verifica los permisos de tu base de datos Firebase. Asegúrate de que tu configuración de seguridad en Firebase Database o Firestore permita las operaciones de lectura y escritura según tus necesidades. Puedes revisar y ajustar las reglas de Firebase en la consola de Firebase bajo la sección de Database Rules.
Control de Errores en las Promesas: Asegúrate de que estás manejando correctamente los errores en tus llamadas a Firebase. Por ejemplo, si estás utilizando promesas o async/await para las llamadas a Firebase, asegúrate de capturar y manejar los errores con catch() o un bloque try/catch.


firebase.database().ref('/path/to/data').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    } else {
      console.log("No data available");
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });



CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing): Si te encuentras con errores relacionados con CORS, especialmente cuando trabajas en un entorno de desarrollo local, asegúrate de que tu servidor esté configurado para permitir solicitudes de tu dominio o utiliza herramientas que puedan manejar CORS, como proxies de desarrollo.
Depuración de la Red: Utiliza las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador para revisar las llamadas de red. Asegúrate de que las solicitudes a Firebase se estén realizando correctamente y de que no haya errores o códigos de estado inesperados en las respuestas.
Documentación y Foros: No dudes en consultar la documentación oficial de Firebase para obtener más detalles sobre la implementación correcta y solución de problemas específicos. También puedes buscar o preguntar en foros como Stack Overflow donde problemas similares pueden haber sido discutidos y resueltos.
Espero que estos pasos te ayuden a solucionar el problema. Si el error persiste, sería útil que compartieras más detalles específicos del error o fragmentos del código para tener una mejor comprensión del problema.
